# Solving $y' = y^{2} + 1$ if $y(0) = 1$

Tags: calculus

The solution to the initial-value problem $y' = y^{2} + 1$ with $y(0)=1$ is $y = \tan(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$. I would like to show that this is the correct solution in a way that is analogous to my solution to differential equation $y' = y - 12$.

**Solution to Differential Equation**

If $y' = y - 12$,
\begin{equation*}
\frac{y'}{y - 12} = 1 ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\left(\ln(y - 12)\right)' = 1 ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\ln(y - 12) = t + C
\end{equation*}
for some constant $C$. If $C' = e^{C}$,
\begin{equation*}
y = C' e^{t} + 12 .
\end{equation*}

Comment: What's the derivative of $\arctan\circ f$ for a sufficiently well-behaved $f$?

Comment: If $f$ is a differentiable function of $t$, $\frac{d}{dt} \tan^{-1}(f) = \frac{f'}{f^2 + 1}$.

Comment: Can you relate what you just answered to your question?

Comment: $\frac{f'}{f^{2} + 1} = 1$.

Comment: According to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, since $\frac{d}{dt} \tan^{-1}(f) = 1$, $\tan^{-1}(f) = t + C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: So, $f = \tan(t + C)$.

Comment: Since $f(0) = 1$, $C = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be written as

$$\frac {y'}{y^2+1}=1 $$
and after integration

$$\arctan (y)=x+C $$

for $x=0$, it gives

$$\arctan (1)=0+C=\frac {\pi}{4} $$

thus

$$y=\tan (x+\frac {\pi}{4}) .$$

Comment: Slightly confused on the downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

You can also check directly, since you have been given a solution.

If someone gives you $y(t)=\tan (x+\pi/4)$ and asks you to verify that it solves the IVP above,
$$
y(0)=1\\
y'=1+y^2
$$
All you have to do is check that 
$$
y(0)=\tan(\pi/4)=1
$$
and
$$
y'=\sec^2(x+\pi/4)=\frac{\cos^2(x+\pi/4)+\sin^2(x+\pi/4)}{\cos^2(x+\pi/4)}=1+\tan^2(x+\pi/4)\\
=1+y^2
$$
as required.

Interestingly, I think it's actually easier to just solve this by separation of variables, 
$$
\int\frac{\mathrm dy}{1+y^2}=x\implies \arctan y=x+C\implies y=\tan (x+c)\\
y(0)=1\implies \tan(c)=1\implies c=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$